# Parallax Floating/Easing Effect

Tags: jquery, css, parallax

Anyone have a recommendation on how to achieve this effect of elements floating as you scroll? https://www.couleecreative.com. Preferably jQuery/CSS.

Comment: in chrome right click and select view page source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [jquery.parallax-scroll](https://github.com/alumbo/jquery.parallax-scroll) plugin. 

Below an example of how to use it::

> Translation to the right by 650 pixels when vertical scroll position
>   is over 90 pixels, then translation to the bottom by 500 pixels when
>   vertical scroll position is over 400 pixels during a scroll distance
>   of 60 pixels

```
<li data-parallax='{"x": 650, "from-scroll": 90, "distance": 0}' data-parallax2='{"y": 500, "from-scroll": 400, "distance": 60}'>3</li>
```